# Bi-directional voltage translation with ESD and EMI protection

Tags: esp32, level-translation

I plan to use the following circuit connected to a ESP32 GPIO line which is 3.3V to control stepper driver and, if needed, serve as a digital input (0V/5V).

[image]

[Diode](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/ESD-Protection-Devices_BORN-PESD5V0S1BBN_C314264.html) is there for ESD protection and [ferrite](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Ferrite-Beads_FH-Guangdong-Fenghua-Advanced-Tech-CBM160808U121T_C62708.html) for EMC. Using [n-channel MOSFET](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_VBsemi-Elec-SI2302ADS-T1-VB_C725156.html).

Will it work? Thank you.

Comment: What's going to stop the TVS from burning if an over-voltage happens? What EMC specifications are you hoping to meet and what are the spectral characteristics of the "ferrite"?

Comment: Thank you for reply, added links to ESD diode and ferrite bead datasheets. Diode is designed for ESD protection so I hope it won't burn out when shot with a pulse. It probably will fail if e.g. 20V DC are applied but that's outside of usage limits for my PCB.

Comment: You missed Andy's the most important question: What EMC spec do you need to meet? What requirement made you think that FB is needed?

Comment: Apologies! Just the regular FCC Part 15b / CE light industrial. It's a programmable controller so I don't necessarily have the control of what's being sent over the `ZSTEP-3V` line. `ZSTEP-5V` can also be connected to a long wire which could bring external EMI to the board. Ferrite bead seemed like a cheap way to give some basic protection against high-speed noise.

Comment: It may work and it may not. Asking if a particular EMC solution will work is likely not to be answered in the affirmative.

Comment: Got it, at least there are no glaring problems which is good news :) Thanks!

Comment: It's not that anyone's afraid of answering; it's the case that those folk who have been through EMC compliance testing will know that so many things can go wrong and that compliance is dependent on so many other things being right that have nothing to do with the circuit you showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a level shifter, that's a perfectly fine solution, it will work. Although if you need input only, then perhaps it's a bit overkill as that's a bidirectional shifter. I've often been a bit lazier myself and used a resistor divider, but that's my applications.
As far as ESD, that's a simple way to do it that works. The diode has some ratings, so presuming they suit your needs that's grand.

As far as EM, well that's a bit different. A significant proportion of EMC is layout, and the parasitics that it generates. That circuit could well pass or fail depending on the layout, so the schematic alone is not enough to comment on. Even then, as others have said, one can only suggest something is good or bad practice.

You are mixing EMI/EMC though, and they are different. EMI protection is to protect from electromagnetic interference. EMC, electromagnetic complaince, is to ensure your device doesn't emit excessive electromagnetic radiation, in accordance with applicable standards. It sounds like you're concerned about both

From an EMI perspective, the ferrite would offer you some protection against noise that had already coupled into the 5V line, but I don't think it would actually matter. Being connected to a digital input, you'd need such a colossal amount of noise before it began to malfunction that it wouldn't seem to be feasible, and it would border on radiation hardening to protect against.

From an EMC perspective, if you're planning on doing compliance testing, the ferrite doesn't give you much. You don't have to make an input compliant for any and all connections, and you'd presumably test it without the optional input connected, or test it with something known. 
Being connected to an ESP32, I presume whatever's being sent over it will be relatively slow, but I might add the option of slew rate limiting after the level shifting if I was particularly worried.